# TWTweetComposeViewController cansendtweet is true even when user revoked app in twitter

Tags: ios5, tweets

IOS 5.x using the TWTweetComposeViewController class.  All is well even with the

```
 if ( [TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet] )
```

UNLESS the user revokes access for the app on twitter, then the above is still true and when trying to send a tweet an error message appears with

```
Cannot be sent because the connection to Twitter failed.
```

This can be fixed if the user goes to SETTINGS / TWITTER / USERNAME

A message will come up

```
The user name of password is incorrect.
```

If the password is retyped, the app will be re authenticated on twitter and all is good again.

1) Is there anyway to capture the error under program control and then can inform the user to redo the settings?

2) How come the canSendTweet is true even when the app has been revoked?

Answer (score 1):

1) No as it's a system level issue so not something you can control or manage directly from you apps sandbox

2) canSendTweet merely confirms that twitter is accessible on that device and that an account has been set up. It's not intended to identify if the user has given you access to their twitter account.

If you want to know if your app can access the users twitter you should use:

```
- (void)requestAccessToAccountsWithType:(ACAccountType *)accountType 
                  withCompletionHandler:(ACAccountStoreRequestAccessCompletionHandler)handler;
```

located in the Accounts Framework

```
#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>
```

As an example this is one way of doing it:

```
        accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
        twitterAccountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:twitterAccountType 
                     withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                         if (!granted) {
                            // Access denied by the user - do what you need to do
                             NSLog(@"Authenticated : User rejected access to his account.");
                         } 
                         else {
                             // Access granted
                             // Do what you want here to send the tweet or whatever
                         } 
                     }];
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue can also be caused by having the time and date of your device set to a time other than the current time. Twitter will not allow you to authenticate from the Settings app in this case, and it also causes the TWTweetComposeViewController to fail with the "connection to Twitter failed" error message, even though canSendTweet returns true.